# Elementary freezes after locking screen

Tags: greeter

After I lock the computer (super + L) the computer sometimes freezes. 
The screen is black (backlight on), no tty is accessible. I'm forced to force-reboot.

I've tried several kernels with no success.

Hardware:
Dell Latitude E5450
VGA: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics

Current Kernel: 
4.4.25-040425-generic

Comment: Also, generally after the forced reboot when I log it only a empty screen appears (the wallpaper), no app dock / panel and I have to enter into tty and restart lightdm

Comment: I have the same happen to me sometimes. It usually happens to me when I've closed the lid of my laptop (it suspends). I can also access a terminal by pressing Alt+Ctrl+F1.
I would check the ElementaryOS launchpad issue queue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos

Comment: Did you try to login as a visitor or an other profile?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my HP Probook G4 laptop. It is issue of 16.10 kernel. Just turn off in Bios your ATI or Nvidia videocard. Graphical system will work on CPU. On 17.04 kernel hybrid graphical system works fine, you just need some time to wait for updates.